# Using gcc@9 instead of gcc 10

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, homebrew

I have the most up to date version of gcc on my Mac OS Big Sur machine via `brew install gcc` but now I would like to have `gcc@9` in addition or in place of it. I have `gcc@9`in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.3.0_1` but I can't find a way for my system to use this rather than `gcc10`. When I do `brew ls --versions gcc`, it still returns `gcc 10.2.0_4`.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your previous question.  Edit your previous question — don't ask a new one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but it attracted 10 views in 7 days. If there is no way to bump via making edits then likely there will be no attention in the near future....

Comment: Maybe you should choose different tags.  I didn't see the question.  Since it is about a C compiler, adding the [tag:c] tag would work wonders for its visibility.  I do track the [tag:gcc] tag and [tag:version-control], but the question wasn't shown to me AFAIK.  The [tag:version-control] tag is more appropriate to questions about version control systems such as Git, SCCS, RCS, Mercurial, Bazaar, Subversion, Fossil, … so I suggest you replace that tag with [tag:c].

Comment: Was the command `gcc@9 --version` even attempted in a Terminal? I don't have my Macbook handy right this second, but I believe you can also see what's available in `/usr/local/bin`, where brew puts its symlinks. Nothing stopping you from placing your own symlinks, either.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for the comment. Actually I had never tried `gcc@9 --version`before. Doing so gives me `zsh: permission denied: gcc@9`however. Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: @sweenish However when I do `brew ls --versions gcc@9`I get `gcc@9 9.3.0_1`

Comment: This is probably the end of the line for what tips I have. I don't put gcc on my macs. However, my earlier comments still largely apply since you've made no indication about changing symlinks yourself or looking to see what's already available.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks, I haven't really symlinked before so i'm probably just being naive. I had tried `brew link gcc@9`and it says `Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.3.0_1`